# Does anyone have an mstest runner for Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mstest, jasmine

Given the rather extensive existing library of tests in MStest, I would like to add jasime for testign javascript and inbclude those new test in the MSTesting framework so that there is minimal disruption to current TDD patterns...

If anyone knows of an existing mstest runner for Jasmine, I would appreciate it.  Would save time now having ot build one myself.  Also opne to other MSTest integration ideas as well, just in case I'm chasing the wrong solution...

Our current continuos integration/source control solution is TFS 2010.

Development is with VS 2010 and the resharper plugin.

Answer (score 6):

[Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) runs Jasmine or QUnit tests in the headless PhantomJS browser from the command line.  I'm currently working on publishing it's output to TFS 2010 called from a [PSake](https://github.com/psake/psake) build script.  My hope is that with some XSLT or other magic, I can get the JS tests to fail the build if one doesn't pass.

Comment: If you figured out how to make it integrate nicely with TFS 2010 I would love to merge your work back into the Chutzpah.

Comment: I never did figure out how to get the Jasmine output into TRX format, but you can fail a PSake script with a non-zero return code from the VS2012 test runner found at $env:VS110COMNTOOLS..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe /UseVsixExtensions:true and the latest Chutzpah

Answer (score 3):

On my [blog](http://aspnetperformance.com/post/Unit-testing-JavaScript-as-part-of-TFS-Build.aspx) I showed how to run Jasmine tests as part of a TFS 2010 build, in a way that fails the build when the Jasmine tests fail. This also works when running unit tests from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work for me since I'm getting an exception: System.AggregateException ... ---> System.IO.IOException: Invalid handle.

Answer (score 1):

The solution mentioned in the [Matt Perdeck's article](http://aspnetperformance.com/post/Unit-testing-JavaScript-as-part-of-TFS-Build.aspx) is awesome and works as expected. The reason you are getting IOException is because of chutzpah version. You need to use chutzpah.console.exe **/silent** to get it working.